# Running jasmine with rails 3.1 and coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, jasmine

I'm trying to setup a rails 3.1 project with coffeescript and jasmine for tests.

I have followed the tutorial by [pivotallabs](http://pivotallabs.com/users/jdean/blog/articles/1778-writing-and-running-jasmine-specs-with-rails-3-1-and-coffeescript) but I'm getting the following error:

```
Internal Server Error

undefined method `static_root=' for #<Sprockets::Environment:0x00000102128718>
```

How can I solve this?
Manu thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that, you can follow this [pivotal article](http://pivotallabs.com/users/mgehard/blog/articles/1683-using-jasmine-to-test-coffeescript-in-a-rails-3-1-app). It works for me.

Make sure to start guard before to write yours specs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest Rails and Sprockets gems? This looks like [Sprockets issue #172](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/172), which was fixed.